# While loop blocking promise from resolving

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
async function awaitFetch(urlString) {
    try {
      let status = await fetch(urlString);
      return status;
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

let response = null; 
let url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
awaitFetch(url).then(function (resolve) { response = resolve.status });
while (response === null) {};
console.log(response);
```

The while loop runs eternally, and I find that `response` never changes from null because the promise never resolves. Why does my code behave this way? I expect the loop to stop executing when the asynchronous code turns `response` into `200` or what have you (something besides `null`), but that never happens. The loop executes forever, and my `console.log()` is never run. Why is this?

All that I'm really trying to do is pause execution until `response` is an actual response, and then log it. I also have the constraint that I can't put the `console.log()` within the `.then()`. If the event loop is blocked by my while loop, what is a way that I can pause execution until `response` updates without putting my `console.log()` in an `async` function or a `.then()`??

Comment: Keep in mind that async does not mean multi-threaded. If you want your JS multi-threaded, you can use Web Workers. Async just means the code will run a little bit at a time, with other code in between, until it's done and it settles. A while loop running in between never finishes, so it can't return to check on the async code, and you get an infinite blocking loop.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded, so a while loop will block all processing. Post-completion logic for async tasks still must run on that same single thread.

If you want to wait on a Promise, instead of doing a spin loop, use `await`:

```
async function() {
  let url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
  const { status: response } = await awaitFetch(url);
  console.log(response);
}
```

...or put your logic in the `.then` callback.

```
awaitFetch('https://stackoverflow.com')
  .then(function (resolve) { 
    const response = resolve.status 
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: I can't have my console.log() in the .then() or in the async function. In reality, my log function represents thousands of lines of code that need to wait for me to get response. For various reasons, they need to be free standing.

Comment: There's no way to avoid the use of callback functions or `await` for asynchronous code in JavaScript. Maybe you could rephrase the question with more details on why you can't use an async function for this. There's almost certainly a way that you can indeed use an async function.

Answer (score -3):

Can you try putting your call to awaitFetch inside your while loop block?

Comment: This would be brilliant